# How to make usb 3G modem signal stronger with aluminum foil antenna?

Tags: radio, usb-device, mobile

I'm in an area with weak signal reception, but I'd like to make my 3G connection better at very low cost.

I heard using aluminum foil as reflecting surface and placing the modem in some way in front of it will enhance the signal. Is there a particular rule on how to place the modem and what form must aluminum surface have?

Illustrations are welcome.

Comment: Did the sieve + alumimium foil solution actually work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

[image]

I never tried so I can't tell you if it works, but the idea seems to mimic a satellite dish, using the aluminium foil as a parabolic reflector.

[Source](http://mattscradle.com/booster-how-to-increase-boost-3g-usb-broadband-signal/)